# How to successfully resend a POST request and get the correct respond without knowing the actual payload

Tags: http, post, payload

I've been working on to capture a multiple post requests from an android app for testing purpose.

Unfortunately, I'm stuck in finding a way to get the actual payload of the request by using a request sender to resend the request. I could get 200 status code but I could only get a wrong respond, and that is not what I expected. I'm hoping to get any advice in here if it's possible?

The request is sent via a `POST` method. 
The request address looks like this(from my perspective it doesn't have a body, does it?)

```
http://proxy.ABC.ABC.com/ABC/qryunreadmsgcount.do?d=2&m=1&t=803514
```

Please correct me if the description or the title needs further editing .

Cheers

=========================================================================
Edit:

this is the respond that I got

```
Preview: {
        "respbase": {
            "status": "false",
            "returncode": "000002",
            "returndesc": "必填参数[clientrequest]"
        }
    }
Server: nginx/1.14.0
Date: Thu, 19 Jul 2018 01:44:38 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 4
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type, Accept-Language, Origin, Accept-Encoding
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

* Preparing request to http://proxy.ABC.ABC.com/vboxserver/qryunreadmsgcount.do?d=2&m=1&t=803514
* Using libcurl/7.54.0 LibreSSL/2.0.20 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.24.0
* Enable automatic URL encoding
* Enable SSL validation
* Enable cookie sending with jar of 7 cookies
*   Trying 101.XXX.XXX.XXX...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to proxy.ABC.ABC.com (101.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 80 (#75)
> POST /ABC/qryunreadmsgcount.do?d=2&m=1&t=803514 HTTP/1.1
> Host: proxy.ABC.ABC.com
> User-Agent: insomnia/5.16.6
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 0
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.14.0
< Date: Thu, 19 Jul 2018 02:13:24 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 96
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

* Received 88 B chunk
* Connection #75 to host proxy.ABC.ABC.com left intact
```

And this is the request sender I've been using:
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Add the code you are using

Comment: @Facundo  thanks for the quick respond. Yeah I've tried, let me add it.

Comment: @Facundo It's been updated.

Comment: How is this question related to Android?

Comment: @Facundo its a request sent from an Android app. But I can delete it if you find it's irrelevant.

Comment: What did you use to develop the Android app, Java? Kotlin? C++?

Comment: @Facundo Sorry I can't see your question is relevant to my question.

Answer (score 0):

For those who might want to know the answer:

Burpsuite is very handy in dealing with this

:)